# Instagram feed access token in shopify

Tags: shopify, access-token

I am new to shopify and I wanted to add the Instagram feed on the website I'm working on. This website is using Retina theme and I think this is not an updated theme. I read some articles like [here](https://outofthesandbox.com/pages/instagram-access-token) about missing instagram feed in shopify store homepage and they said I need to have an access token. Now that I have my access token, I don't know what to do with it. I mean, where can I insert this token? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
 {{ 'instafeed.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
 {{ 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
 <h2 class="instagram_heading" style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000;">Store Name</span><span style="font-weight:normal;"> On Instagram </span><a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/shopgear101/"> UserName</a></h2>


<section class="twitter-feed footer-bottom-margin">
  <div id="instafeed" class="photo_list list-inline">
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: 'userid', //Put The user id here..
        accessToken: 'accesstoken', //Put The access token here..
        limit: '10',
      template: '<div class="twitter_img" style="background-image: url\(\{\{image\}\}\)"><div class="inner_image text-center"></div><a target="_blank" href="\{\{link\}\}"><div class="inner_image"><span class="text_like"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;\{\{likes\}\}</span></div></a></div>'
    });
    userFeed.run();
</script>

<style>
  .twitter_img{
     float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    padding-bottom : 20%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */

    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover; /* you change this to "contain" if you don't want the images to be cropped */
  }
  .inner_image {
    position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: rgba(0, 0 , 0,.5);
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .twitter_img:hover .inner_image{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
  }
  .text_like{
    font-size: 22px;
    position: relative;
    top: 47%;
    left: 45%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 420px){
    .twitter_img{
      width: 50%;
      height: 190px !important;
    }
  }
</style>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I forgot to delete this question before. I managed to fix the issue myself.

Comment: So it would be a good idea to answer your own question and accept as answer by yourself.

Comment: Home it'll help other people. @claudios

Answer (score 0):

Well, it requires some coding skills. Try to use free Instagram apps from Shopify Apps Marketplace. You won't need to do anything except copy & paste the embed code:

https://apps.shopify.com/instagram-feed

https://apps.shopify.com/instagram-photos

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case link gets removed.